# how to save values in wpf after switching combobox (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have `two selections` in my ComboBox and 3 `RadioButtons`. And I want to save my last `RadioButton`-Selection every time I switch my `ComboBox`.

So I need following:
I have Item `"Test1"` and checked `RadioButton 1`. Now I switch to `"Test 2"` and RadioButton 1 should be saved at Test 1. When I switch back to `"Test 1"` `RadioButton 1` should be checked, because it was "saved" before.

Hopefully it's clear what I meant. Thanks for helping me out in advance.

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RBTN1" GroupName="Test" Content="Test1"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="RBTN2" GroupName="Test" Content="Test2"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="RBTN3" GroupName="Test" Content="Test3"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="CMBBX" SelectionChanged="CMBBX_SelectionChanged" />
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    CMBBX.Items.Add("Test 1");
    CMBBX.Items.Add("Test 2");
  }

private void CMBBX_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you mean, could you draw a diagram? Or add more introduction. Normally, you can also choose to create a variable to store the selected object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the mappings between the selected item in the `ComboBox` and the selected `RadioButton` in a dictionary. This code should give you the idea:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, RadioButton> _items = new Dictionary<string, RadioButton>();
    private string _selectedItem;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _items.Add("Test 1", null);
        _items.Add("Test 2", null);
        CMBBX.ItemsSource = _items.Keys;
    }

    private void CMBBX_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // save
        if (_selectedItem != null)
            _items[_selectedItem] = GetSelectedRadioButton();

        _selectedItem = CMBBX.SelectedItem as string;

        // restore
        if (_selectedItem != null 
            && _items.TryGetValue(_selectedItem, out RadioButton radioButton)
            && radioButton != null)
            radioButton.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private RadioButton GetSelectedRadioButton()
    {
        if (RBTN1.IsChecked == true)
            return RBTN1;
        if (RBTN2.IsChecked == true)
            return RBTN2;
        if (RBTN3.IsChecked == true)
            return RBTN3;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CMBBX_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CMBBX.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            RBTN1.IsChecked = true;
            RBTN2.IsChecked = false;
            RBTN3.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else if (CMBBX.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            RBTN1.IsChecked = false;
            RBTN2.IsChecked = true;
            RBTN3.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
```

You can use this method for other situations too. I hope it'll be helpful for you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).